# Java RMI Netbeans Packages

Tags: java, netbeans, package, rmi

When using Netbeans I am able to run RMI applications if I don't put the source files in a package, however when I try and split it up into packages.
I start to get class not found exceptions any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Post some code.  Class not found exceptions usually mean that your classpath isn't set properly.  I don't mean a CLASSPATH environment variable, either.  NetBeans (and all IDEs) ignore environment variables and ask that you tell them where to find .class files.

Find out what NetBeans thinks your classpath is and make sure it's set properly.

Answer (score 0):

RMI server returns the output with the package name and interface name. So, when the interface moved to another package, the server can't identify that. That is the problem you have.